# Change font size of paragraph on being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am relatively new at css wanted to know how to  change the font size of the paragraph on being selected. I have seen  a similar example 
https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

But this one only changes the color of the highlight ::selection selector for some reason dose not work with the font size

Answer (score 1):

From [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp):

> Only a few CSS properties can be applied to the ::selection selector:
>   color, background, cursor, and outline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this dosen't  solve the problem :(

Comment: While it doesn't solve the issue (you need javascript for this), it does explain why "for some reason" it doesn't work on your end. You can't with CSS

Comment: As @SterlingArcher mentioned, you will need javascript to do this. Here is a demo of how can be done with javascript+jquery https://jsfiddle.net/z85wudzg/